# Python-How to take a dictionary as input

Tags: python, input, dictionary, python-3.x

**Specs:** Python3.3.2

**What I intend to do:**

> Take a dictionary as input and return one as output, but the values
>   are now the keys and vice versa

**Question:** I believe that I can figure out the key-and-value-switch part. But I don't know how to take a dictionary as input.(and keep the object type as `dict`)

**What I tried:**

```
a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
print(a)
```

**Result:** `{'a':1,'b':2}`. **BUT**:

This turned out to be a string object, as is shown using `type(a)` and getting `<class 'str'>` as result.

Comment: You could try the solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary

Comment: Your "What I tried" part gives me a dict in the python 2.7 interpreter!

Comment: @zaphod: You're using Python 2, the OP is using Python 3. Try ``raw_input`` as an equivalent.

Comment: @zaphod sorry about the confusion!

Comment: ... well ... I'm not certain the OP as clearly understood the terms of his assignment? "Take a dictionary as input and return one as output" -- Should "input" be interpreted literally as "from the input() function"? Or, as I am inclined to think, should we understand "write a function receiving a dictionary _as argument_ and returning an other one such as ..." Or am I just too tired to read things correctly?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux your reading make more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you input in a terminal, will always be a string! Hence, if you enter a correct dict you have to transform it first by executing the given string like this:

```
import ast
a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
d = ast.literal_eval(a)
print d
```

However, looking at the comments to your question. I don't think somebody would ask you to parse a `dict` like that from the commandline. Hence, the task probably wants you to just write up a function to receive a dict and print it out, or probably play with it so you can see the difference between mutables and immutables in python and how they are passed around!

Cheers!

Comment: @user2246674 It is seen around here very often. It's way better and safer than using `eval()`.

Comment: Another option would be to use ``json.loads``.

Comment: Thanks! I think your reading of the question make more sense than mine. Parsing is a little too complicated for a beginner as I am right now.